# generating and mapping two sets of numbers

Tags: python, mapping, numbers

I have 2 numbers 25798709 and 25716544 representing the minimum and maximum values of some consecutive numbers with each number differing from the preceeding number by one eg. 25798709,25798710, 25798711................25716544  I want a python code that will convert these figures to 1,2,3,4,5,.............. and map the 1,2,3,4,5 to the original figures in two columns: 
Like:

```
  1     25798709
  2     25798710
  3     25798711
```

Comment: So the "mapping" is simply subtracting or adding `25798709-1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```
print(*['{0}\t{1}'.format(*i) for i in enumerate(range(MIN,MAX+1), 1)], sep='\n')
```

For python2.6 or 2.7 just add `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
mapping = dict(enumerate(range(25716544, 25798709)))
for i in iter(mapping):
    print i, '->', mapping[i]
```

I should warn you that this is zero-based. So 0 -> 25716544, 1 -> 25716545, etc.

Comment: Why use dict when you could just iterate through the object returned by enumerate?

Comment: The OP wanted a mapping, i.e. a dict. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

```
# make it work in both Python 2 and 3
from __future__ import print_function
try: xrange
except NameError: xrange= range

def my_enumerate(num1, num2):
    start= min(num1, num2)
    end= max(num1, num2) + 1
    for data in enumerate(xrange(start, end), 1):
        print("%d\t%d" % data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work and start from 1:

```
for idx, num in enumerate(range(25716544, 25798709), 1):
  print idx, ' ', num
```

To start from 0:

```
for idx, num in enumerate(range(25716544, 25798709)):
  print idx, ' ', num
```